# Where and how to perform segues in VIPER architecture?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, segue, transition, viper-architecture

As a beginner, I used to perform segues in `ViewControllers`. Moreover, Apple encourages such approach, because `UIViewController` has methods `performSegue` and `prepareForSegue`.

But learning VIPER, I read that `Router` is responsible for transitions between scenes. And the second thing is that according to VIPER flowcharts like this:

[image]

`Router` mustn't be tied with `View`.

I absolutely don't want to refuse from using `segues`, because it is extremely powerful and allows me to easily transfer data between `ViewControllers`.

So, how should I perform transitions between `ViewControllers`?

Answer (score 7):

In pure VIPER all transitions should be performed in Router. So you would not be able to use segues if you'll choose to implement VIPER

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer using Storyboard ID rather than segues.
For example :
1. Put a relevant storyboard ID for your view.
[image link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUBhb.jpg)

2. Then you can access that view like :
`let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login")`

3. You can pass data with it like: `loginVC.type = 0`

4. You can access it whenever you want like:
`navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I am a little late. I am pretty sure you figured-out your way. Though I think someone might find this useful.

Your router should create the module and decide how to go to that module. The presenter tells the router where to go, and the router tells **how** to go there.

Each module's router knows it's own view controller.

**How** the routing is done is up to you and the code you implement in your router's "routing" function. 
If it's just pushing the next module to your navigation stack, your routing func will call the next router's 'createModule()' and then you just do something like :

```
self.viewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextModuleVC)
```

Storyboards' segues approach is not VIPER in it's nativity because the 'view'(View controller in this case) knows about routing decisions, where in VIPER it's only responsibility is the UI, sending actions to the presenter and being updated by it.

If you'd still want to do this, you can create the segues between the view controllers and then when a user taps a button, for example, you can send the action to presenter, the presenter will notify the router and the router will then call 'performSegue'. 
In my opinion this is not a good approach.

Comment: So we shouldn't use Segues in VIPER (or CleanSwift)?

Comment: For VIPER - Depends on you. If you want to stick to the architecture, then you should probably do that programmatically via the router. 

At the end of the day tho you should think why you started using an architecture in the first place. But the short answer to that is that it should serve you, and not vice versa.

Regarding CleanSwift - It is using more of a VIP approach which have a router as an optional thing afaik